# From $1031$ foot high balloon angle of depression to HQ is $81^\circ8'$, find distance from point on ground below balloon to HQ

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> From a balloon $1031$ feet high, the angle of depression to the ranger headquarters is $81^\circ8'$. How far is the headquarters from a point on the ground directly below the balloon?

I know this problem seems simple, but I feel like there is not enough information. The ranger headquarters could be many different heights and distances away from the balloon. Here's a crudely made drawing in MS paint of how I'm interpreting it

[image]

Is my interpretation valid? Or is there a crucial piece of information that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the fact that the question is not very well worded in that it doesn't state the height of the ranger base. In that case, I think we should assume that the ranger base is positioned on the ground at height $h=0$. Hence, this becomes a pretty easy question that can be solved with basic trigonometry.

We have $\triangle ABC$:

[image]

\begin{align}
\angle A & = 90° - 81°8'\\
& = 8.8\overline6 \\
\tan(8.8\overline6) & = \frac{x}{1031} \\
x & = 1031\tan{8.8\overline6} \\
& \approx 160.8358272~ \text{ft}
\end{align}

Hence the horizontal distance between the balloon and the ranger base is $160.84$ ft. (2 d.p.)

Comment: I don't know either; I can't tell what the question is trying to say. The answer choices all range from 151-166 feet though.

Comment: Oh I realize that you have it pretty much right except we both defined the angle of depression incorrectly

Comment: @suomynonA Oh geez, that's a pretty big mistake. I can only laugh at both our mistakes, as we got the answer completely wrong. Perhaps I'll edit my answer to make it correct.

Comment: Yep that's right now haha